# Cauchy Goursat problem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let k be the rectangle with corners $-2-2i,2-2i,2+i,-2+i$. Evaluate the integral:
$$
\int_k \frac{\cos(z)}{z^4}dz
$$
Would the best way to do this problem be to integrate along each contour line using the Cauchy-Goursat theorem:
$$
\int_k f(z) \, dz = \int_b^a f(z(t))\frac{dz(t)}{dt} \, dt
$$
Is there a way to do one integral and include all of the contour lines on the rectangle.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Cauchy-Goursat,
$$\int_k\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}dz=\frac{2\pi i}{n!}f^{(n)}(z_0)$$
and so
$$\int_k \frac{\cos(z)}{z^4}dz=\frac{2\pi i}{3!}\sin(0)=0$$

Comment: Oh yea thanks, I was over thinking it so much.